# How to define read-only replicas in Spanner?

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

I want to explore read-only replicas in Spanner. I have options to create nam-3 or nam-6 multi-region spanner( read-only can be created only on multi-regional spanner). When I select either of the options on the right panel I get replica details as follows

For num-6

```
Replicas
2 read-write replicas in us-central1 (Iowa) - default leader region
2 read-write replicas in us-east1 (South Carolina)
1 read-write replica in us-west1 (Oregon)
1 read-write replica in us-west2 (Los Angeles)
```

For num-3

```
Replicas
2 read-write replicas in us-east4 (Northern Virginia) - default leader region
2 read-write replicas in us-east1 (South Carolina)
```

I do not see read-only replicas in both of the options. Do I need to anything different here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Authoritative information about available configurations is available here:
https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/instances#available-configurations-multi-region

Only `nam6` and `nam-eur-asia1` multi-regional configurations offer read-only replicas.

I've verified that descriptions in Cloud Console are in line with your observations and this is incorrect. Thank you for noticing, I'll pass the report to the dedicated team to address it.

UPDATE 2019-10-04: this is fixed now.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, do you want me to open a ticket with google-cloud?

Comment: @NareshNagarajan this is not strictly required, only if you'd prefer to. FYI, internal issue reference number for this is 140426085. I hope that our public documentation provides enough guidance for you to proceed, thanks.

Comment: Cloud Console UI has been fixed now with the accurate information. I can confirm that public documentation is correct now and was correct on Sep 3rd.